# How to disable GoLand "auto import logrus" feature?

Tags: goland

My organization maintains a common logger library which can accept and record our own context data. With it, normally I write logging code like this:

```golang
log := commons.Logger(ctx)
// ...
log.Errorf("some error happens %v", someData)
```

But if I somehow forget/delete the first statement, GoLand will automatically add `logrus` to my import path, which won't cause any compile/runtime error, until I find log data are missing from our own log collection system later.

I'm wondering is there a way to turn off this "auto logrus" feature?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `goimports` as a `File Watcher`?

Comment: No, I never go get goimports. And my GoLand's file watcher configuration is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. Go to Preference 【Go】->【Imports】and unselect "Add unambiguous imports on the fly"。

[image]

Comment: That does not seem as the proper fix. The "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" is designed so that it will only import imports who are unqiue in the GOPATH/Go Modules. If the IDE imports logrus automatically, it means that it cannot find the import for your internal package. You can either provide more details here, or open an issue on our tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and we can sort this out later. As it is, I discourage people from using this as a proper fix.